# lua-lgi libnotify add_action callback not being called

Tags: lua, linux-mint, cinnamon, libnotify

I followed the hello world example on [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications) to set up lua-lgi and libnotify, successfully getting a notification that looks and acts the samea s if using `os.execute("notify-send...")`. Notify-send does not allow user actions, from what I've gathered, so I am attempting to directly use the libnotify library to display a notification with a button. When clicked in the notification, it should open a file. I am able to call the function described [here](https://developer.gnome.org/libnotify/0.7/NotifyNotification.html#notify-notification-add-action) with lua, using (building from the hello world example):

`Hello:add_action("button", "Open", function(notification, action, user_data) os.open("gedit tmp") end)`

which successfully displays a button with the label "Open" in the notification. However, the callback function is not called, so the file does not open. I also noticed when running the script, it actually finishes executing before the notification has fully appeared, so if the program is not running anymore when the button in the notification is clicked, then that's one reason why the callback isn't being called, if it's working correctly up until that point. This is my first experience with lua-lgi, so I'm not sure how these types of callback functions translate into lua, or if they're even supported, which is probably what I'm really trying to understand here. Any help is appreciated regarding this issue, or insight into an alternative to displaying a notification with a button and callback via other means.